# How to cast only few columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 39 columns. I need to cast the type to int of the columns from 5(name=1980) to 39(2013). how do i do that?

d[1980:2013].astype(int)      [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo0ih.png)

Answer (score 1):

df.loc[:,1980:2013].astype(int)

Comment: Shouldn't 1980:2013 be in quotes??

Comment: regardless column name solution would be `df.iloc[:, 5:].astype(int)`

Comment: @hacker315 because the column name is int

Comment: @Seawise I think it might raise 'index out of range exception'... because it would take the given number as index position

Comment: `import pandas as pd`\n
`import numpy as np`\n
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,4)*100)`\n
`print(df)`\n
`print(df.loc[:,1:2].astype(int))`\n

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for i in range(5,40):
    d.iloc[i,:]=map(int,d.iloc[i:])
```

Comment: I think it would be slow... Try it with %timeit

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using a nested for-loop that starts with the index range.

```
for x in df.columns[5:40]:  <--pulls the columns you want to type cast
    for y in df[x]:  <-- pulls the array from said column
        y = int(y)   <--type casts the entire arrary

...repeats for each column inside your range.
```